# How to select text layers below or behind other text layers in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, text, selections

I have an image with several text layers on top of each other. Because they are rotated, they all have the same 'boundary box'.

I want to edit several of the text layers, but when I click on the text, it selects the wrong layer. Even if I actually click on the letters I want to edit (so not on the text of the wrong layer). Even when I set the wrong layer invisible, GIMP still selects that layer.

How can I force GIMP to choose the right text layer?

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13390/gimp-trying-to-move-selected-text-layer-but-moves-background-layer

Comment: Did you try also locking the layers that you don't want to edit?

Comment: Yep, locking doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by moving the layer I wanted to edit up to the top, editing, and then moving it back down.

Answer (score 0):

Make the other layers invisible by clicking on the eye in front of the layer name in the "Layers - Brushes" dialog.

Comment: Hello ldx, thanks for your answer and welcome to GDSE!

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't work for me. Might be the version of GIMP I'm using.